# Getting some odd errors

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, abstract-class, overriding

I am taking Ap Computer Science at my High School, we are programming in Java and for my final project, I am making an automatic math calculator for Astronomy.  I am trying to make a drop down box with the list of equations, I have coded the drop down box and action listener along with the general GUI, and I am getting an error "The type mainScreen must implement the inherited abstract method.  I am getting a lot of other errors as well but this is the main one. java.awt.event.ActionListener.actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)".  I am not the best with abstract classes. As I am still fairly new to Java coding I am not the best at it.  Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class mainScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
 private static final String[] equations = {"Distance Mod", "Luminosity", "Mass of Binary"};
 JComboBox equationList = new JComboBox(equations);
 Jlabel whatEquation = new JLabel();

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    mainScreen equat = new mainScreen();
    centerFrame(equat);
    equat.setVisable(true);

  }
  public mainScreen()
  {
   setLayout(new Flowlayout());
   setSize(900, 800);
   setTital("Astronomy Equations");
   setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   equationList.setSelectedIndex(1);
   equationList.addActionListener(this);
   add(equationList);
   add(whatEquation);
  }
  public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    if(e.getSource() == equationList)
    {
      JcomboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource());
      String msg = (String)cb.getSelectedItems();
      switch(msg)
      {
        case "Distance Mod" : whatEquation.setText("Please put in the known info and put a '0' if data is not known.");
            break;
        case "Luminosity" : whatEquation.setText("Please put in the known info and put a '0' if data is not known.");
            break;
        case "Mass of Binary" : whatEquation.setText("Please put in the known info and put a '0' if data is not known.");
            break;
        default : whatEquation.setText("Whoops. an error has occured please try again. :)");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your main error is little more than a careless error. Read carefully the line that you think is correct: actionPreformed is wrong. It should be actionPerformed.

Comment: This is why you should always preface method overrides with the `@Override` annotation. If you had done this, the compiler would have told you that you were not actually overriding the method that you thought you were.

Comment: [Another duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119191/why-do-i-keep-getting-an-line-75-errormust-implement-the-inherited-abstract).

Comment: Unrelated suggestions: Class names should begin with an upper-case letter, and doing this will help others to better understand your code. You're better off not having your GUI classes implement your listener interfaces. Instead use an anonymous inner class here.  It's `setVisible(true)`, not `setVisable(true)` -- another careless error that the compiler should warn you on.

Comment: Also, for future questions, you will want to make your question title more informative. "getting odd errors" doesn't tell us what your problem is. Better to state something like, "seeing error: mainScreen must implement the inherited abstract method" or something else that briefly tells us exactly what problem you're facing.